# Problems on Ubuntu Dell laptop when unplugging or replugging AC power

Tags: networking, 20.04, dell, touchpad, power-management

I'd like to apologize in advance that this question is insufficiently specific. I'd like to make it more specific and provide relevant info from `journalctl` or other sources as needed, so please do let me know if there's info I can provide here that's useful.

I have a Dell precision 5570 running Ubuntu 20.04 (and Linux 5.15). I've noticed weird issues that seem to always occur when I unplug or replug AC power. Specifically, my touchpad will often start to become intermittently non-responsive and sometimes outright fail to work (in this case, a USB mouse works) and my Wi-Fi will often fail and be unable to reconnect, even after power cycling Wi-Fi. I've also tried restarting the wpa_supplicant service and unloading and reloading `iwlwifi`, but those don't work either. The only thing I've found to work is rebooting the computer. These issues don't always occur - I can sometimes unplug or replug AC power without noticeable problems, but they do occur often enough to be very disruptive to my work (though infrequently enough to make it difficult to troubleshoot). I also experienced similar issues with a Dell precision 5550 that I had previously and on Ubuntu 18, which I used to run on the 5550. I update my software and laptop firmware regularly.

I also boot NixOS from an external USB drive on the 5570. I've never encountered the Wi-Fi issue on that and I've very infrequently (but not never) encountered the touchpad issue in NixOS.

I would try Windows on this too, to try to identify to what extent this is a hardware v. software issue, but of course Microsoft does everything in its power to prevent Windows running from a live USB. The fact that I experience these issues a lot less on NixOS makes me think that this is at least to some extent a software issue and not entirely (or maybe not at all - I don't know) a Linux kernel problem.

Can anyone provide advice for how to go about diagnosing and solving these problems? I know that distributions often enable battery power-saving features. The symptoms make me think this is a possible source of problems. What software is Ubuntu using for this? What should I be looking for? What should I search for in `journalctl`? Is this possibly a firmware problem?

Comment: Does NixOS use the same kernel?

Comment: Oh good question. No it's newer: 6.4.12. Though until recently I had it on 5 something and results were similar. I agree that to do a fair comparison NixOS should also be on 5.15.

Answer (score 0):

Dell AC adapters are known to cause all sorts of weird issues, possibly by design. First thing to try is replacing the AC adapter. I had to replace mine maybe 3 times over 10 years with a Precision and an Inspiron notebook. There are good aftermarket alternatives out there that don't break.

Comment: Any idea what the problem with them is? Are they not able to regulate well to changes in line or load? Are they noisy? Presumably, it's not an outright failure or I would have noticed.

Comment: Or, if the problem is an outright failure then I think that's probably not the issue in my case.

Comment: What I mean is this: Dell AC power units have an unfortunate tendency to fail over time (ALL my Dell adaptors (3 or 4) failed within a couple of years). Reason unknown. Your question included "Can anyone provide advice for how to go about diagnosing and solving these problems?". My advice is that the first thing to try is a different AC adapter because in many cases that solves the issue. Trying to diagnose further requires too much effort and Dell support is usually not helpful. Dell support site was full of angry people complaining about failing adapter the last time I checked.

Comment: Most common symptoms are (i) adapter not recognized message on startup or (ii) simply not charging the battery without any message (but nonetheless providing power), or (iii) mysteriously forcing processor to slowest speed. Your case of course is different, but isolating a possibly faulty adapter is easy and fast. Anyway, this is the first thing I would try.